# Move ALL git commits dates 1 day into the future

Tags: git, bash, date, git-filter-branch

My system time was incorrectly set during a game jam, so all my commits are exactly 24 hours before anyone else's. I'd like to try doing a filter-branch:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
ad="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"
cd="$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE"

if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "wilbefast" ]
then
    ad=date_plus_one(ad)
    cd=date_plus_one(cd)
fi

export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$ad"
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$cd"
'
```

I can't figure out how to parse and modify the date though :S I'm not a bash pro I'm afraid; Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

GIT_AUTHOR_DATE and GIT_COMMITTER_DATE are in unix time, so you can just add 24 hours worth of seconds to these values (86400 seconds)

```
ad=$[ $ad + 86400 ]
cd=$[ $cd + 86400 ]
```

Comment: `$[...]` is deprecated syntax; use `ad=$(( ad + 86400 ))` instead. `bash` also supports `ad+=86400`.